# Доступ к серверу на TCP/IP по статическому IP

Tags: c#, tcp, tcp-ip, клиент-сервер, .net

Всем доброй ночи!

Разрабатываю клиент-серверное приложение на C#, где посредством TCP протокола необходимо передать данные серверу, а затем получить ответ. Сервер - обычное консольное приложение, запускающееся на компе с Windows 7. Не секрет, что, используя TCP протокол, клиенту необходимо знать IP адрес сервера.

У меня есть две машины (клиент, сервер), находятся они рядом друг с другом, оба подключены к интернету. Собственно, если каждый раз запускать клиент и сервер после переподключения к интернету, то IP сервера будет изменяться, собственно как и IP клиента. 
Как сделать так, чтобы клиент как-то автоматически определял IP сервера и коннектился к нему? То есть каждый раз просить пользователя в клиенте ручками ввести айпишник сервера - не вариант.

Копаю в сторону Dns. Насколько я понимаю, если поднять каким-то образом свой dns сервер и преобразовывать хост, заданный в клиенте, в IP, то все будет так как нужно? Или я вообще не в ту сторону смотрю? Подскажите ваши идеи. Спасибо, друзья. )

Comment: Необходимо именно самому приблуду написать?
Я бы воспользовался любым Dynamic DNS сервисом и коннектился бы по доменному имени как белый человек...
А что значит рядом стоят? Они не в одной сети?

Comment: @k0balt, Нет, саму ее писать не нужно. Я правильно понимаю, если зарегистрировать свой домен dns, то dns будет выдавать нужные IP каждому клиенту? Посоветуйте тогда, какой нибудь хороший DDNS.
 
Нет, они не в одной сети. Они оба только к интернету подключены. Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Как оно работает, можно почитать, например, тут: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_DNS   
Там же есть списки сервисов.   
В кратце - регистрируете доменное имя, ставите на "сервер" утилитку, и доменному имени будет соответствовать ваш IP сервера. 
Я когда-то пользовался dyn.com, но они вроде уже не предоставляют такой услуги.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо DNS можно поиграться и с широковещательным UDP. Сервер рассылает раз в минуту свой IP. Клиент после запуска проверяет прошлый адрес и если там пусто - ждёт уведомления на определённом порту. Не скажу, чтобы прям универсальное решение, и минусы есть, но может и подойдёт.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм:

1-й компьютер (server)

-Получает IP (например - checkip.dyndns.org)

-Отсылает IP на почту

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-email-attachment.htm

2-й компьютер (client)

-Получает IP по почте

-Вставляет IP в conf-файл программы

Для получения IP по почте, можно использовать расширяемую библиотеку, например ImapX

https://imapx.codeplex.com/

Comment: А что если письмо не моментально будет доставлено? Тогда клиенту придется ждать и возможно долго, пока придет заветное письмецо. Быть может я чего-то не понимаю, но по моему это как-то не правильно)